# Attempting to insert characters via shell script bound to hotkey

Tags: openbox

I added the following to `/root/.config/openbox/rc.xml`:

```
<keybind key="C-A-t">
        <action name="Execute">
            <command>/root/my-applications/test1.sh</command>
        </action>
</keybind>
```

The `test1.sh file` consists of an executable shell script which outputs `ñ`.
The idea being to tie the key combination to the output, so when I press <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd> it will output an `ñ`. However, it doesn't work; pressing it in (for example) Geany does nothing. I have reconfigured openbox. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about `X`'s key compose feature? Enable it then compose-key,n,~ will generate “ñ”. (The [Compose key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key) Wikipedia article has some good links at the bottom.)

Comment: Is your script executable? What happens if you change the line for :`<command>sh /root/my-applications/test1.sh</command>`

Answer (score 2):

First off, why are you running X as root? That's a really bad idea considering all of the security implications.

Secondly, binding a key to a script that outputs "ñ" is not the same as giving that to a program (on the contrary, it likely just goes straight to `/dev/null`). You need to look into using something like [`xdotool`](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml).

Comment: I'm using puppy linux. I've tried using "xdotool key ntilde" but that doesn't work either.